# Iptables NAT logging

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have a box setup as a router using Iptables (masquerade), logging all network traffic.

The problem:

Connections from LAN IPs to WAN show fine, i.e. SRC=192.168.32.10 -> DST=60.242.67.190

but for traffic coming from WAN to LAN it will show the WAN IP as the source, but the routers IP as the destination, then the router -> LAN IP.

I.e. SRC=60.242.67.190 -> DST=192.168.32.199
     SRC=192.168.32.199(router) -> DST=192.168.32.10

How do I configure it so that it logs the conversations correctly?

SRC=192.168.32.10 -> DST=60.242.67.190
SRC=60.242.67.190 > DST=192.168.32.10

Any help appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 1):

the info you need is only in the connection tracking table. Have a look at conntrack(8) how to get it. Logging it in real time might be tricky though, maybe something using -j ULOG and ulogd.

Answer (score 1):

To log all of the information you want, you would need two log rules. One to log the data from the wan interface to router, and a second to log the packet from router to LAN host.

In other words, As the packet passes through your routing tables, the destination will be re-written. If I understand correctly, you want to see that packet's information before it's rewritten, and after (so you can see which host its going to).

The rules may look something like this: 
Existing rule which shows wan to router:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix " New Incoming Packet"
```

New Additional Rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -d LAN_HOST_IPADDR -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix " [>] NEW FORWARD"
```

Or for extra credit, and to keep things a little cleaner, create a new chain for traffic forwarded to the LAN HOST, something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -N forward_to_mypc
iptables -t nat -A forward_to_mypc -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix " [>] New Forward"
iptables -t nat -A forward_to_mypc -j DNAT --to <address_of_mypc>
```

Then use the new chain like this:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i <WANADAPTER> -p tcp --dport 3389 -j forward_to_mypc
```

That would forward any port 3389 tcp packets coming in the wan adapter, to your LAN pc, and if the packet is new, it would get logged.

Comment: What does `forward_to_mypc` look like? this is not really clear?

Comment: The `-N` parameter creates the `forward_to_mypc` table and then we append to it with `-A`. We build it up and then direct packets toward it with the PREROUTING rule that follows.

Answer (score 0):

you can try logging in -t nat -L POSTROUTING before the -j SNAT --to-ip ... line

HTH
Oliver

Comment: I don't have the -j SNAT line.
I have the logging configured as:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j LOG
the same for PREROUTING and OUTPUT

I also have:
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG
the same for INPUT and FORWARDED

Are you saying I should change it to:
iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -j LOG, dropping the -A switch?

Cheers for the reply

Answer (score -1):

$iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

where eth0 is the router interface